# Can you create a pattern for HTML input fields with a minimum number of letters of a certain type?

Tags: html, input, input-field

I want to create a pattern for an HTML input field that needs to have at least 10 numbers in it and may also have spaces and a plus sign on top of that, but it's not required.

It's important that numbers and spaces can be mixed though. Also, the whole field can only have 17 characters all in all.

I'm not sure if it's even possible. I started doing something like that:

```
pattern="[0-9+\s]{10,17}*"
```

But like this, it's not guaranteed that there are at least 10 numbers.

Thanks in advance! Hope the question doesn't exist already, I looked but couldn't find it.

Comment: You probably want `pattern="(?:[+\s]*\d){10,17}[+\s]*"`. If you need to match a more specific pattern, you should  share the requirements.

Comment: It's worthwhile mentioning that you should still sanitise the input in your server code as it's trivial to bypass these pattern filters

Comment: Thanks to both of you @WiktorStribiżew your answer worked perfectly

Comment: @Martin yeah I'm doing that but thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
pattern="(?:[+\s]*\d){10,17}[+\s]*"
```

The regex matches

- `(?:[+\s]*\d){10,17}` - ten to seveteen occurrences of zero or more `+` or whitespaces and then a digit
- `[+\s]*` - zero or more `+` or whitespaces.

Note the pattern is anchored by default (it is wrapped with `^(?:` and `)$`), so nothing else is allowed.